# Can't debug api calls with cordova project in Visual Studio

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, cordova, jquery-mobile, webview

I'm developing a cordova app with jQuery Mobile inside visual studio. 

 I've got an api call inside an Ajax call which sens me the correct or incorrect values through a `HttpResponseMessage`. But for some reason, this call always seems to give me a fail return.

I'm trying to debug the Action in Visual Studio to see what goes wrong, but it doesn't seem to get triggered when I run it from my app. I'll explain how I'm trying to achieve this:

1. Inside Visual Studio I'll start debugging and add a breakpoint
   inside my Action. IIS will tell me which port localhost is hosted
   on.
2. I change the url of my ajax call to localhost
3. I run the application on my Android device with it being attached to my browser through `chrome://inspect` or with `gapdebug` (both work).
4. I trigger the ajax call and while it should trigger inside Visual Studio, it doesn't..

I've made a mockup on codepen to see if it would trigger in Visual Studio, and strangely, **it does trigger** in Visual Studio.

```
var testData = [{
  name: "Language",
  value: "1"
}, {
  name: "RegistrationCode",
  value: "123789"
}, {
  name: "EmailAddress",
  value: "someEmail@domain.com"
}, {
  name: "Password",
  value: "az"
}];

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:2144/api/appusers/verifyregistration",
    data: testData,
    type: "post" 
  }).done(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("fail");
  });
```

**So basically my question is, how can I debug the api call from my cordova app on Android? A normal debug doesn't work and with Attach to process I'm not quite sure what to attach on.**

---

**Additionally:** When I change the url back to the nog localhost url and test that in my codepen, I'll actually get my result. Unfortunately I can't share the url, but the issue here is that **the url in my ajax call works in codepen.io, but doesn't work in my android application (exact same code)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

1. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`
2. add `<access origin="*" />` inside config.xml